# Delay on jquery keyup?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create my own "autocomplete", but when I type a letter (eg. w for word), then there's a splitsecond delay - enough to annoy the eye.

Here's my testcode:

CSS:

```
#txtSearchAutocomplete {
   background-color: white !important;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   font-size: 20px !important;
   border: none !important;
   color: gray;
 }

 #txtSearch {
   background-color: transparent !important;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   font-size: 20px !important;
   border: none !important;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<span style="position: relative; display: inline-block; width:100%; top: -18px;">
    <input type="text" id="txtSearchAutocomplete" disabled >
    <input type="text" id="txtSearch">
</span>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#txtSearch").focus();

  $("#txtSearch").keyup(function(e) {
    var autocomplete = ['word', 'excel'];
    var $txtAutocomplete = $("#txtSearchAutocomplete");
    var txt = $("#txtSearch").val().trim().toLowerCase();

    $txtAutocomplete.val("");

    if (txt == "") return;

    for (i = 0; i < autocomplete.length; i++) {
      var entry = autocomplete[i];
      if (entry.indexOf(txt) == 0) {
        $txtAutocomplete.val(entry);
        break;
      };
    };
  });
});
```

And a fiddle sample:
https://jsfiddle.net/25gwz1qu/1/

If you type in the letter w - delete it - type it again and so on, then you will notice a small delay. It might seam that the delay is a bit longer in IE.

Any idea how to get rid of this delay?

Thanks

Comment: Try `$("#txtSearch").on('input', function(e) { ... })`

Comment: Super - that did the trick. If you add it as an answer, I can mark it as answer. Thanks!! :)

Comment: Just FYI, I can't reproduce this issue. it works fast on my browser :)

Comment: @choz, may be you are running this on a super computer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the delay you are seeing is because the event triggers once the user lets go of the key. In that case, the `oninput` is the way to go. The event triggers when the textbox input changes.

```
$("#txtSearch").on('input', function(e) { ... })
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look on my solution with comments that explain why I did those changes and here is a Working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OBender/5rthu99r/).
On my machine the auto-complete is almost instant after those modifications.

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  // i had moved all selectors outside the function so the havy dom selection will happen only once
  var autocomplete = ['word', 'excel'];
  var $txtAutocomplete = $("#txtSearchAutocomplete");
  var $searchElement = $("#txtSearch");
  $searchElement.focus();
  // In Jquery on works faster than on key up, cause user lets go of the key.   
  $searchElement.on('input',function(e) {
    var txt = $searchElement.val().trim().toLowerCase();
    // I had replaced the element to be a div and not a input cause the div element is much light weight and faster to draw for the browser 
    $txtAutocomplete.text("");
    if (txt == "")
      return;
    for (i = 0; i < autocomplete.length; i++) {
      var entry = autocomplete[i];
      if (entry.indexOf(txt) == 0) {
        $txtAutocomplete.text(entry);
        break;
      };
    };
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#txtSearch").focus();

  $("#txtSearch").on('input',function(e) {
    var autocomplete = ['word', 'excel'];
    var $txtAutocomplete = $("#txtSearchAutocomplete");
    var txt = $("#txtSearch").val().trim().toLowerCase();

    $txtAutocomplete.val("");

    if (txt == "") return;

    for (i = 0; i < autocomplete.length; i++) {
      var entry = autocomplete[i];
      if (entry.indexOf(txt) == 0) {
        $txtAutocomplete.val(entry);
        break;
      };
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: this has been already answered in the comment. Is there any different approaches you are suggesting??

Comment: Please add explanation on why/how this works. Code only answers are aweful.

Comment: no,almost same,as i haven't seen that comment,thanks for information.